# How to build flatbuffers message with existing struct buffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, flatbuffers

I'm sending an ack to a received message in Node.js server and I want to echo the messageId back to the client. Currently I'm parsing the messageId from a buffer to string and building the ack from the string. Parsing the id to string and back is unnecessary but I'm unable to build the ack directly with the stuct buffer.

This is how it works when messageid is passed in as a string.

```
function createAck(messageId) {
    let builder = new flatbuffers.Builder;
    const request = MyServer.MessageAck;

    request.startMessageAck(builder);
    request.addMessgeId(builder, createUUID(builder, messageId));
    const requestMessage = request.endMessageAck(builder);

    return builder.finish(requestMessage);
}

function createUUID(builder, messageId) {
    let uuidBytes = new Uint8Array(uuidParse.parse(messageId));
    let dataview = new DataView(uuidBytes.buffer);

    return MyServer.UUID.createUUID(builder,
        flatbuffers.Long.create(dataview.getInt32(0, true), dataview.getInt32(4, true)),
        flatbuffers.Long.create(dataview.getInt32(8, true), dataview.getInt32(12, true)));
}
```

I would like to pass in the messageId as a buffer directly taken from the message with

```
request.addMessgeId(builder, messageId);
```

But I'm getting an error: *'FlatBuffers: struct must be serialized inline.'*

Here is the struct:

```
struct UUID {
    low_bytes: ulong;
    high_bytes: ulong;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the fact that structs must be stored in-line, i.e. their bytes must be written to the buffer in between `startMessageAck` and `endMessageAck`. You can't refer to a struct stored elsewhere.

You should be able to copy the existing struct without using the intermediate `Uint8Array` and `DataView` however, something along the lines of (not tested):

```
request.addMessgeId(builder, MyServer.UUID.createUUID(builder,
    messageId.low_bytes(), messageId.high_bytes());
```

Assuming `messageId` is a reference to an incoming `UUID` struct, can't tell from your code.

Even better would be if you could copy the struct using the JS equivalent of C `memcpy`, but that would require some hackery directly on the `ByteBuffer` in the `builder` that the current API doesn't directly support, so is probably not worth it for just 2 fields.

Comment: Thank you, yes this works (with slight modification) and is a step to better: `request.addMessageId(builder, MyServer.UUID.createUUID(builder, messageId.lowBytes(), messageId.highBytes()));`